# OBJ exported model appears very bumpy

Tags: objects, export

I'm new to Blender so please bare with me - I imported a photogrammetry model made in AgiSoft and patched it up in Blender. I then grouped together multiple cube meshes that I used to patch up the original model with the dollhouse so it's just one group. I have set all the materials to shadeless and have not added any lights to the scene.

My model in blender (view mode set to material) look like this below.
[image: Blender View]

Why though when I export the group as an obj, it comes out looking like this? (below editing for animation in VideoCopilot's Element 3D v2):
[image: Exported Model]

My export settings that are checked off are:

- Apply modifiers
- Include edges
- Write normals
- Include UVs
- Write materials
- Objects as OBJ groups

Ideally, I would like my model to be exported and when imported into another software, look like how it appears on Sketchfab and in Blender - not bumpy, shadeless, and top green floor and other meshes included with the photoscanned dollhouse mesh.

In short, I can't get Blender to export all the grouped meshes together into one OBJ model even though they're grouped together in Blender. Likewise, why isn't the model as smooth and shadeless as it appears in Blender.

**UPDATE:** I've managed to export my OBJ to include all the necessary meshes. In Element 3D I then just had to manually check "draw backfaces" for all the materials *BUT* the interior of my dollhouse is still looking very bumpy like it does in the picture originally posted. How do I get my exported model to appear smooth like it does when uploaded to Sketchfab here? (copy & paste and delete space in below link)

https: //skfb.ly/6s9rI

Comment: So screenshot from Blender GUI is the one of desired result? Or otherwise? To export meshes as one object no need to group them, join them into one object.

Comment: Correct - the first screenshot from Blender is the desired result. The second screenshot is what it is showing up looking like in another animation software. With some lighting I've managed to do away with some of the bumpiness of the texture and mesh but why does it look so different between the two softwares in terms of how bumpy and rough the mesh is?